# Limit display to 10 in foreach statement PHP

Tags: php, function, for-loop, foreach

I have an API that's showing almost 100 trades that I want to limit to just 10. I've tried

```
if($bitcointrades == 10) break
```

but that didn't work. Do I run a for loop after I pull the data? Should I break up the functions into two parts as opposed to using elseif to present $trades?  Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php

require_once('bitcoin.class.php');

$data = new Bitcoin();


$type = $_GET['type'];

$currency = $_GET['currency'];

if($type == 'ticker') {

$bitcoinlive = $data->getPrice($currency);

echo '<h2>1 Bitcoin is currently worth <span class="bitvalue">' . 
number_format((float)$bitcoinlive['last'], 2) . ' <span class="upper">' 
. $currency . '</span></span></h2>';
echo ' <p><span><i class="icon-arrow-up-circle"></i> High: ' . 
number_format((float)$bitcoinlive['high'], 2) . '</span> <span><i 
class="icon-arrow-down-circle"></i> Low: ' . 
number_format((float)$bitcoinlive['low'], 2) . '</span>';

} elseif($type == 'trades') {

$bitcointrades = $data->getTrades($currency);

foreach($bitcointrades as $trade) {
if($trade['type'] == 'buy') {
$ttype = '<span class="green"><i class="icon-plus-circle"></i> Buy 
Order</span>';
} else {
$ttype = '<span class="blue"><i class="icon-circle-minus"></i> Sell 
Order</span>';
}
echo' <tr> <th scope="row">' . $ttype . '</th> <td>' . $trade['price'] 
. ' <span class="upper">' . $currency . '</span></td> <td>' . 
$trade['amount'] . '</td> <td>' . $data->timeAgo($trade['date']) . 
'</td> </tr>';

}

}
```

Comment: If you can't limit the results from the API, you could use `foreach(array_slice($bitcointrades, 0, 10) ...`.

Comment: What is your API link, maybe it has its own command to limit the results. Are you using api.hitbtc.com? – in that case check this documentation, you can directly ask for limit result command/10 https://api.hitbtc.com/?shell#trades, its better to use API command than getting 100 result then short it..will save some run time

Comment: I'm using cex.io. Is hitbtc just as reliable?

Comment: The command you need is `limit` , send it with your API Query, that is a better approach .

Comment: @TomBeckerle, not sure about hitbtc reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal `if($bitcointrades == 10) break` isn't going to work.

`$bitcointrades` should be an array with trades which you define as `$trade`.

You need to use an iterator `i` like in the example below:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

foreach($bitcointrades as $trade) {
    if($i==10)
        break;
    // your logic here
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference that this is an "elseif" statement? I tried the first one with no luck. let me try this one.

Comment: I got a bunch of parse errors, but I could have entered it incorrectly. It makes more sense to limit the API query so I’m going to go that route. Thanks guys I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can finish a foreach execution using break so you can use a cnt and break

```
  $my_cnt = 0;
  foreach($bitcointrades as $trade) {
    if ($my_cnt >= 10) {
       break;
    }
    if($trade['type'] == 'buy') {
      $ttype = '<span class="green"><i class="icon-plus-circle"></i> Buy 
      Order</span>';
    } else {
      $ttype = '<span class="blue"><i class="icon-circle-minus"></i> Sell 
      Order</span>';
    }
    $my_cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this way

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($bitcointrades as $trade) {
if ($trade['type'] == 'buy') {
    $ttype = '<span class="green"><i class="icon-plus-circle"></i> Buy Order</span>';
} else {
    $ttype = '<span class="blue"><i class="icon-circle-minus"></i> Sell Order</span>';
}
echo ' <tr> <th scope="row">' . $ttype . '</th> <td>' . $trade['price']
    . ' <span class="upper">' . $currency . '</span></td> <td>' .
    $trade['amount'] . '</td> <td>' . $data->timeAgo($trade['date']) .
    '</td> </tr>';
$i++;
if ($i == 10) {
    break;
}
}
```